# Laser printer for PCBs

Tags: printer

I need a new laser printer for general (paper) usage. Normally, I'd get "whatever", nothing fancy; I do not have high volume, speed nor quality requirements. I have been very happy with my Samsung ML-1865W, but it's starting to show its age a little bit.

One area where that printer failed for me was printing solid, deep black areas (for PCB creation, in my case). There were always, from the beginning, stripes and occasional white spots. It obviously gets worse as the toner empties, but even with a brand new toner cartridge it is not optimal. Not *too* bad, mind, you can somewhat use it for that purpose, but it's not really fun.

In contrast, the expensive Xerox at my office produces pitch black, very nicely resolved images that lead to 100% perfect results on the PCB, but it obviously takes up like 0.5m³ of space, so is not really an option for home.

Now. I'm looking for a general home usage laser printer which manages to produce consistent black areas. Everything else is not important. It will be driven by a windows machine and I don't mind whether it's connected via USB, Ethernet or WIFI (one of the latter two would be a nice bonus, of course). Form factor should be similar to the Samsung at 13.4" x 8.8" x 7.2" (somewhere in that ball park, does not need to be exact of course). Manual feed is optional.

Thank you!